# Can't read by loop foreach Externall List

Tags: development, external-list

If I tried to view in Element one of three External List I geting this error:

**Unable to display this Web part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.**

After I call it from Code i Getting this error:

[image]

I tried this with simplest code.

I can't manage what it is a problem. Could You Help me, please.

```
  SPList kontrakty2List = witryna.Lists["CRM_Kontrakty"];
                SPQuery kontrakty2Query = new SPQuery();
                kontrakty2Query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='lsm_name'/></OrderBy>";
                SPListItemCollection kontrakty2Grupa = kontrakty2List.GetItems(kontrakty2Query);

                foreach (SPListItem oKontrakty2ListText in kontrakty2Grupa)
                {
                    Label4.Text += oKontrakty2ListText["lsm_name"].ToString();
                }
```

Comment: Could you translate the error into English please?

Comment: Second that. If we can understand what the error is saying, maybe we can point out where the error is.

Comment: Naturally, here is transletting:

Could't find default method of serching for grup View associate with operation specified method searching (reading element) QS_Kontrakty_Aktywne_FKRead Item unit WADB02 in namespace units http://wasp03.wawa.qumak.pl.